# Why wolfram alpha find no solution to $x^\frac13= -1$?

Tags: exponential-function, wolfram-alpha

Surely, $x=-1$ is the only solution.

But, wolframalpha says there is no solution in the real field.

I think this is because they transformed $x^\frac13$ to $e^{\frac 13(\ln x)}$.

But why did they use this identity to solve the equation? What is the benefit of 
doing this?

Comment: I think WA will give $x=-1$ if you ask for the real-valued root (instead of the principal root).

Comment: what is the principal root?

Comment: It depends on how you define $x^{1/3}$. If you use $x^{1/3} \equiv e^{\log(x)/3}$ then the definition is only valid for $x > 0$ so there are no solutions. If you instead use the definition $x^{1/3} \equiv \text{sign}(x)|x|^{1/3}$ then $(x^{1/3})^3 = x$ for all real $x$ and $(-1)^{1/3} = -1$.